# subscription System view cannot display filter column information

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

subscription System view cannot display filter column information

```
db001 ❯ show subscription on db001;
+--------------+----------------+------+
| SUBSCRIPTION | DESTINATIONS   | MODE |
+--------------+----------------+------+
| sub001       | 127.0.0.1:8912 | ALL  |
+--------------+----------------+------+
Query took 0.001 seconds.
```

Expect the system to attempt to display filtered column information

version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 842fc0e37a28327f14805f7ebe7ca1a85fca721c